# What are the advantages of using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, build-process

My manager is forcing me to use MSBuild for building my application.

I developed my application in ASP.NET MVC.

Here are some questions I have:

1. what are the advantages of MSBuild?
2. Is there any other build tool better than MSBuild?
3. What are the drawbacks on simple build of projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSBuild is great. It is similar in concept to NAnt, but slightly different with some of its tasks or implementations.

Once you get used to it, you will be cranking out the build files. Take a look at a csproj file - it is a MSBuild file (note that the .sln solution file is very similar to an MSBuild file but it technically isn't a MSBuild file (yet))*. Building custom tasks for it is very simple, there are plenty of guides on teh interweb which walk you through how to do it.

If you are looking for alternatives, then i would go to NAnt. It is free, and has a huge amount of community support and extra tasks available. I haven't used it for a few years though, so i can't comment on its exact state at the moment.

There are no real drawbacks to using MSBuild, unless you count the amount of time it will take to get up to speed with it, and the amount of time you have to spend researching it.

From your questions it sounds like you don't really have much of a build process in place - take the time to do it, once you have you will wonder why you didn't do it sooner.

<sub>* Edited in response to comment from Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi</sub>

Comment: csproj files (as well as others like vbproj) are MSBuild files.

Comment: Ahh, ok... was it the solution file that wasn't a proper MSBuild file? Thanks Sayed, good to see you on here :)

Comment: @slugster: You should edit your answer and delete the part where you state that csproj files are not MSBuild files. Not everybody reads all the comments.

Comment: slugster, any links you can share to help get us started on preparing a build process? This isn't something I have ever looked into.

Answer (score 2):

Advantages with MSBuild:

1. Available as it is installed as part of .NET
2. It shares the build system with Visual Studio

Drawback: Well, the XML syntax may not be intuitive.

Comment: thanks @@Arve...Is there any other Build which is batter then MS Build?

Comment: I have not use anything else than make and that is not better or NAnt which is very similar.  rake may be better, but I have not used it.

Comment: Starting with VS2013/.NET4.5.1 the .NET included 4.0/4.5 MSBuild will no longer receive updates -- starting with .NET5 there might be no MSBuild which gets installed as part of .NET at all: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio.aspx)